# Clear struct, which is member of class in C++

Tags: c++, oop, struct

I want to clear a structure, which is a member of class. Example

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int my_int;
    char my_array[10];
};

class MyClass {        
   public:       
       MyStruct some_struct;
       void myMethod() {  
           // Here I want to reset my structure
           MyStruct = {};
       }
};
```

My assumptions are:

1. MyStruct does not have a constructor, this is POD type.
2. POD type will are initialized by zeros.

Is it correct? Will `my_int` be zero and `my_array` be filled with zeros?

Comment: `MyStruct = {};` => `some_struct = MyStruct {};`?

Comment: *"POD type will are initialized by zeros"*. Depend of the kind of initialization, it is ok here.

Comment: @Scheff: You meant `MyStruct = {};` is better or equal to `some_struct = MyStruct {};` ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 Not quite. But meanwhile, I convinced myself that even `some_struct = { };` should have done the job... [*Demo on coliru*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10a95ed448cb690f)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition is correct (but your syntax is off).  `MyStruct` is an [aggregate type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) and `some_struct = {}` is assignment to a *value-initialized* aggregate, which becomes [*zero-initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) because you are using an initializer consisting of empty braces `{}`. During zero initialization, each element of the array is zero initialized.

Answer (score 2):

It is instead :

```
some_struct = {}
```

Here is the testing code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct MyStruct
{
    int my_int;
    char my_array[10];
};

class MyClass {
   public:
       MyStruct some_struct;
       void myMethod() {
           // Here I want to reset my structure
           some_struct = {};
       }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass test;
    test.some_struct={1, {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}};

    std::cout << "my_int "<< test.some_struct.my_int<<std::endl;
    for (int i: test.some_struct.my_array)
    {
        std::cout << i << "-";
    }

    test.myMethod();
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "my_int "<< test.some_struct.my_int<<std::endl;
    for (int i: test.some_struct.my_array)
    {
        std::cout << i << "-";
    }
}
```

Comment: With special/different rules of initialization, a test is mostly just a hint, not a proof. uninitialized values might be 0 too. Using `constexpr` is better, as no UB and no unitialized values are allowed (even if it might be too restrictive for some tests).

Comment: Thanks for your relecture, I will improve the answer